# How to drag a scaled element

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

I'm making a dragged image.  It works as it should. I also have buttons that scale the image. after scaling, the drug works but it cuts the position. I can't find the right words to describe this behavior.At the first movement the image changes its position slightly

what calculations do I need to do too. to get a smooth drag, after scaling an element.

https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-tree-1zqhf?file=/src/App.js

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep the initial X and calculate only the moved difference.

```
const onMouseDown = e => {
    e.persist();
    var initialX = e.pageX;
    const onMouseMove = ev => {
      var newX = initialX - ev.pageX;
      setX(x - newX);
    };


    const onMouseUp = () => {
      window.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
      window.removeEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);
    };

    window.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
    window.addEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);
  };
```

Link to forked sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-ishizaka-kvmnk?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you for your response but this unfortunately doesn't work

Comment: Yes, getting the page coordinates in this case is more reasonable..I just need to speed up the movement of the element a little...Thank you very much!

Comment: Also... `translate(${x / scale}px, 0px)` Gives me the speed I want